# Would you weight more on the equator or pole of an ellipsoid?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, planets, centrifugal-force

Let's suppose to have a huge planet with an ellipsoidal shape with 2 horizontal axis equal (a=b) and mach greater than the vertical axis. The mass is uniform.

[image]

**Question**: If I was in on the surface of the planet, where would I weight more? on the pole or on the equator?

Is it still possible to use the formula:
$G\frac{Mm}{r^2}$ ?

Disregard the rotation of the planet.

Comment: My instinct is to say you'd weigh more at the poles, your weight in a gravitational field is proportional to r^2. But I don't really know

Comment: The centre of mass is at the centre of the ellipsoid so you are looking for the distance between you and the centre of mass to be smallest.